# regcomp() failed with 'Success'

Tags: c++, regex, validation, filenames

I'm trying to use a regex in order to validate a file-name.
Tried this string

`"^(?!(?:CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|COM[1-9]|LPT[1-9])(?:\.[^.]*)?$)[^<>:\"/\\\|\\?*\x00-\x1F]*[^<>:\"/\\\|\?*\x00-\x1F\\ .]$"`

in online checker : https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html
Works as expected for 'video-'
 -> Fully matches the source string!.

However, using:

```
    bool regexCompile(regex_t &regex, const char *pattern)
    { 
        int res = 0;
        res = regcomp(&regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
        printf("res = %d\n",res);
        if(res) // regex compiled unsuccessfully
        {
            int     rc;
            char    buffer[100];
            regerror(rc, &regex, buffer, 100);
            printf("regcomp() failed with '%s'\n", buffer);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
     }

bool isValidFileName(const char *fileName)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int res = 0;
    // regex not complete
    const char* pattern = "^(?!(?:CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|COM[1-9]|LPT[1-9])(?:\\.[^.]*)?$)[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*\x00-\x1F]*[^<>:\"/\\\\|\\?*\x00-\x1F\\ .]$";
    if(regexCompile(regex, pattern) != true)
    {
        return false;
    }
    res = regexec(&regex, fileName, 0, NULL, 0);
    if(!res)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I get for the filename "video-":

```
res = 13
regcomp() failed with 'Success'
0
```

any extra backslash need to be added in the c-regex version?
Thanks.

Comment: The code you show is not C, it probably is C++ (in which case you should really be using [the C++ standard regex functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)).

Comment: What is `regexCompile(regex_t &regex...`?  Other than "not C code"?

Comment: Note that POSIX [regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), even the ERE variant, do not handle PCRE `(?...)` notations.  For that, you need [PCRE](https://pcre.org/).  So, even if you get around the other problems, the regexes probably won't match what you expect.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't use c++11. I need older version.

Comment: @msadras I'm probably preaching to the choir here, but you know that you've gone to the trouble to pull in a 3rd party regex library here in favor of the just using C++11 which already has regex support... right?

Comment: Wow, regular expressions truly are a write-only language.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks Jonathan. This was the answer, it doesn't support Negative Lookahead (?...).

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
regerror(rc, &regex, buffer, 100);
```

You pass the *indeterminate* value of the *uninitialized* variable `rc`. You should be passing the error you got back from `regcomp`, i.e. `res`:

```
regerror(res, &regex, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```